# PHP Regex - Video files direct links and YouTube links

Tags: php, regex, youtube, mp4

I'm trying to create a regular expression which should match URLs that point directly to *.mp4 file **or** a YouTube video, using PHP.

I've created successfully a regex which matches only a YouTube video and another regex for matching only a direct *.mp4 file, now I want to combine them, which is currently failing.

The requirements of a match is that it has to match a URL with and without http(s) and/or www. So for example the following links should be valid:

```
https://www.example.com/files/video.mp4
http://www.example.com/files/video.mp4
https://example.com/files/video.mp4
http://example.com/files/video.mp4
www.example.com/files/video.mp4
www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx
www.youtu.be/watch?v=xxxxxx
```

I'm using regex101.com for testing and the explanations. At the moment some links are valid according to this tester website, and some links are incorrect while they should be correct actually.

Is there somebody who can tell me whats wrong with [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/PWh4IQ/1)?

```
(http(s)?:\/\/|(w){3}).*\.((?:mp4)|).*(youtu(be|.be))?(\.com)?\/.+
```

Comment: Which links in your list are not matched with the regex? I did a test on regex101 and all are well matched

Comment: Thanks for you reply. For example,  http://www.youtu.be don't match

Comment: With a few changes your expression works fine `(http(s)?:\/\/|(w){3}).*\.((?:mp4)|).*(youtu(be|\.be))?(\.com)?`

Comment: Thanks again, unfortunately according regex101 this will match the *.mp3 file which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As blhsing points out, it's the last forward slash that prevents the pattern from (erroneously) matching all your urls.  The problem is that once you make that last slash optional, the pattern will match ANY url, because all your checks are just optional parts after those `.*` wildcards, which have already matched to the end of the string.  ([example showing these false positives](https://regex101.com/r/7BMaCq/1))

I think you could perhaps make use of a lookahead with [a pattern like this one](https://regex101.com/r/QW5JrJ/6):

```
(?<protocol>https?:\/\/(www\.)?|www\.)(?=.*mp4$|(?:youtu\.?be))(?<url>.*)
```

After the protocol part is out of the way, we "look ahead" with `(?=.*mp4$|(?:youtu\.?be)` to see either 1) mp4 at the end of the string or 2) domain part looks like "youtube|youtu.be".  After the conditional (the lookahead), we just match the rest of the pattern.

Comment: This seems to be the best working regex. Did some tests and according to regex101 no false positives so far. Thank you very much! So the next thing I want to do is to echo this regex into a `HTML` text input pattern attribute. But once I submit this HTML form, any link seems to be valid. It looks like this regex doesn't work in HTML input pattern (after leaving or removing the group names). Is there anything I have to change to get this regex working on a HTML input pattern attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put the mp4 test before the domain name test? The required slash `\/` and extra characters (`.+`) at the end is what prevents your regex from matching any mp4 links.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I moved the mp4 test after the domain test now, and removed the `\/.+` chars, but now it's not matching any YouTUbe link:  `(http(s)?:\/\/|(w){3}).*(youtu(be|.be))?(\.com)?\.(?:mp4)`

Comment: The mp4 test should to be optional, as well as the dot before it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are making a bad use of `.*` expression, which means `any character, between 0 and unlimited times`.

Here is what you want :

```
(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(((youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+)|([\w\/\.]*\.mp4))
```